# Corrupt TrueType Font Detection

Tags: fonts, truetype

I am at present dealing with a corrupt TrueType font. Programs available to me tell me there is a problem with the [`maxp`](http://developer.apple.com/textfonts/ttrefman/rm06/Chap6maxp.html) table -- the `maxContours` member has a value that is too large. Is there a sure-fire way to detect when a `maxContours` value is too high or too low (yes that too can be a problem)? (Fonts are programs so one way to detect a font file is good is to execute them, but this is not an acceptable solution for me.)

I don't need a font library because I can't add one. I have already rolled my own TrueType font parser. What remains is to check if a given value of the above mentioned table is incorrect. I'll then add my parser and the checks to my product.

I don't have the option of rebuilding the font. I am a consumer -- I need to detect if the incoming font is corrupt or not and if it is bail out with as little work done as possible.

In case it helps -- I'm on Windows XP/Vista both 32 & 64 bit and their server versions!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to detect errors, I've found it most convenient to just rebuild the trouble-font with [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).  This can be completely automated, since it provides a rich command line and scripting API.  Plus, You can transform the font into a more convenient format or encoding, if you need.

Comment: I am consuming the input and I need to bail out asap -- so this doesn't work. I'll add this to the question :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, you solved [a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622656/) that I was having.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a sure-fire way to detect when a maxContours value is too high or too low (yes that too can be a problem)?

**Yes.** If you've already built/have a TrueType/OpenType parsing library as you've indicated, this particular value is fairly easy to validate. You'll need to parse each of the glyphs (from the ['glyf' table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm), using the 'loca' table as an index), obtain the number of contours from each glyph, one-by-one, and compare the font-wide maximum to that stored in the ['maxp'](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/maxp.htm).

Note that some other values in the 'maxp' are **not** this simple to test; for example, maxZones, maxTwilightPoints, maxStorage, maxFunctionDefs, maxInstructionDefs, maxStackElements, maxSizeOfInstructions all require parsing of additional tables and for some of those, access to a TrueType scaler and interpreter.

A little background: the 'maxp' (maximum profile) table was intended to be a shortcut/ summary of potentially-useful font-wide maximums, as an aid in memory allocation. So generally speaking, if a value in the 'maxp' is higher than the actual font value, the worst that will happen is that you allocate too much memory...that is, if you're on a platform that actually uses all of the 'maxp' values for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using? I've been able to hack TrueType files quite pleasantly using the [FontTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/) library for Python:

```
font= fontTools.ttLib.TTFont("suspect.ttf")
font['maxp'].maxContours
```

ETA re q edit: So is the question just “what values of maxContours are too low/too high”? As far as I am aware there isn't a documented limit, but I know it's fairly common to ‘add a few on’ to maxContours in case a glyph contains more contours than it states.

(What's maxContours in the troublesome font, and how does it related to the number of contours actually used in glyphs?)

Comment: Thanks! But no, I don't need a parser. I'll edit my question to add clarity.