# Font problems with GDI+

Tags: fonts, gdi+, truetype

I'm having trouble with some ttf fonts not working in GDI+. I cannot seem to find any differences between some of the working and non working fonts. Some can be read and rendered without a problem. For some fonts GDI+ just reports the file as missing (which it is not). Something must be wrong with the format but I cannot for the life of me find out what it is... any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has a decent tool called the [Microsoft Font Validator](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/FontValidator.mspx) which is a free download.

Comment: I still have absolutely no clue what the errors actually mean, but at least I have a list of them... a LONG list for the fonts that do not work which I can pass on to the font provider. Very useful, thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue where the font though Opentype had TrueType outlines but would not render as a drawing using GDI+ (System.Drawing) - The Microsoft Font Validator showed that the font was not ratersizable which takes the mystery out of why some fonts will not work for my application.

Answer (score 5):

GDI+ is picky, it only works with true TrueType fonts and not with OpenType or PostScript fonts, so that support is less than with GDI.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/gdi/article.php/c10621), it may help you out.

Comment: OpenType is a superset term which can apply to either CFF or TrueType glyph outlines (in the 'CFF ' or 'glyf' table respectively). So a TrueType font is an OpenType font, but not all OpenType fonts are TrueType. GDI+ supports OpenType CFF fonts as of Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about fonts is that they are the one of the least understood aspects of programming. I had a similar problem (see [Corrupt TrueType font detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615479/corrupt-truetype-font-detection)). Have a go through my question -- it may help.

Can you post some more details about your problem such as the API you are using, the fonts that work, the ones that don't etc?

Comment: I cannot seem to get any information of what the error actually is - it seems deeply embedded in GDI+. It occurs however when calling PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile(string path). Unfortunately I cannot post the fonts that do not work since our client owns them. examples of fonts that do work are all the standard ttf:s delivered with Windows.

Comment: I am assuming this is an outline font, do validate. If it is, then you may actually have to read up on the TTF specification and have a go at the font file(s) in question (either through MS Font Validator or a custom parser) to figure this out. Note that you may also be bitten by an implementation bug (i.e. a deviation from what the TTF spec says -- which is what had bitten me).

Comment: The odds are -- your client's fonts are corrupt. Do talk to your clients as well. Also, what font related tools do you have in your coterie?

Comment: It is my firm belief that my client's font is corrupt. My main problem is that they look to me for explanations on WHY and HOW it is broken :(. My experience with fonts is as bad as my tool set for fonts. That is why I just love the Font Validator. It allows me to send a list of errors to my client and MY part of the problem is out of the way :)