# Why won't this TTF font work in my browser?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I downloaded a TTF font called "Clunk" and I'm trying to apply it to some text.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: clunk;
    src: url('clunk.ttf');
}

h1 {
    font-family: clunk;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="logo">Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't seem to work and Chrome is giving me two errors:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: (path to the file)
OTS parsing error: incorrect entrySelector for table directory
```

In Firefox, these are the errors that appear:

```
downloadable font: bad search range (font-family: "clunk" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: (path to the file)  test.html:4:12

downloadable font: incorrect entrySelector for table directory (font-family: "clunk" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: (path to the file)  test.html:4:12

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "clunk" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: (path to the file)
```

I Googled around for those errors but this problem seems to be very broad and it was hard to find minimal examples. What would be causing the error in this simple situation?

Comment: Are you using git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/615722/1741346) from 2009 that suggested rebuilding the font with FontForge. I tried that out and it solved the problem, so it appears to have been a problem with the font itself rather than the code.

In this particular case, the letters in the font were "missing points at extrema", which FontForge was able to solve with a single click.

Comment: I have one font, in which i have georgian characters. In ms word georgian characters appear properly, byt when i embed my font with css @font-face directive in web page, georgian characters do not appear. Fixing "missing points at extrema" wit fontforge did not solve the issue. Could you please help me pinpot the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This may help you.

https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff

Basically what you need to do is:

-Convert the .ttf to .woff

I don't know why converting it works. But it always work for me.
Also… delete your cache or change the name of the file.

I hope this helps

Comment: FontForge fixed my problem completely but I tried your website out of curiosity. It fixed the console errors and made the font show up, but it screwed up one of the letters in the font. That's a good backup option but FontForge did the job better and I was able to keep the TTF filetype.

Comment: If the converter I sent you did not convert to perfection, just look up other font converters. Some are better than others. There's nothing wrong with your browsers, code, or thinking. Sometimes the fonts you have are not suitable for browsers. But once you convert it, BAM… It works.

Answer (score 2):

Change Font-family: clunk to  font-family:"clunk"
Then verify your path

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
src: url('/clunk.ttf');
```

Comment: if your path seems to be /font/clunk.ttf, your src should be like this src : `url('/font/clunk.ttf');`

Answer (score 1):

Check your paths, Best practices is to always use a relative paths (Ex:)

```
 src: url('fonts/clunk.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Check header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

[image]

Comment: Changing the src to what you posted didn't change anything. It's finding the file just fine, but it seems like it doesn't like the format or something, even though TTF should be supported.

Comment: hav you given proper headers?

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

`http://yourwebsite/clunk.ttf`

If that can not download (as the first error states), then your file location is not correct. You might have to set an absolute path like:

`http://yourwebsite/somesubpath/clunk.ttf`

Or

`/somesubpath/clunk.ttf`